# Не работает радиопередача данных с Arduino Pro Micro на Arduino Uno

Tags: c, arduino

Доброе время суток! Прошу помочь с выяснением причины не работоспособности собранной схемы.

Дано: Arduno Uno, Arduino Pro Micro, Передатчик FS1000A, Приёмник XY-MK-5V.
Необходимо: Передавать данные с Arduino Pro Micro на Uno.

Передатчик:

```
#include <VirtualWire.h>

void setup() {

  Serial.begin(9600);

  vw_setup(2000);
  vw_set_tx_pin(14);
}

void loop() {

  send("Test message!");  
  delay(2000);
}

void send (char *message)
{
  vw_send((uint8_t *)message, strlen(message));
  vw_wait_tx();
}
```

Приёмник:

```
#include <VirtualWire.h>

void setup()
{
    Serial.begin(9600);

    vw_set_rx_pin(12);
    vw_setup(2000);

    vw_rx_start();
}

void loop()
{
    uint8_t buf[VW_MAX_MESSAGE_LEN];
    uint8_t buflen = VW_MAX_MESSAGE_LEN;

    if(vw_get_message(buf, &buflen))
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < buflen; i++)
        {
            Serial.print(buf[i]);
        }

        Serial.println();
    }
}
```

Пробовал меня местами приёмник и передатчик: Uno + передатчик, Micro + приёмник. Так всё работает.

В чём может быть дело?

Comment: Можно попытаться искать помощи на arduino.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Гугл подсказывает попробовать Serial.write вместо Serial.print. А также попробовать последнюю версию VW.

Answer (score 1):

На *arduino micro* номер *tx pin = 1*

измени

`vw_set_tx_pin(14);`

на

`vw_set_tx_pin(1);`